# To avoid skipping the execution of a function in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a below function in Node.js application. The application skips the execution of this function. I have tried using `wait.for.function()` to wait until the whole function finishes it's execution.But the `wait.for.function()` waits indefinitely even after execution of all lines in the function.

```
function check(msg)
{
  amqp.connect('amqp://serv1:password1@localhost', function(err, conn) {
    conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
      var ex = 'RouteActions';
      var msg='hello'
      ch.assertExchange(ex, 'direct', {durable: false});
      ch.publish(ex, 'vm1', new Buffer(msg));
      console.log(" [x] Sent %s", msg);
      return;
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I want the above function to be fully executed once the function is called before proceeding further.

Comment: Very nice, but why are you shouting?

Comment: can you post your complete code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have enough reputation points to make a comment, so could you show me the code snippet where you make a call to this function. Also provide a callback function to execute this synchronously.

Try something like this :

```
function check(msg, checkCallback) {
    amqp.connect('amqp://serv1:password1@localhost', function(err, conn) {
        conn.createChannel(function(errCreate, ch) {
            if (errCreate || err) {
                return checkCallback("Oops something went wrong while establishing connection...");
            } else {
                var ex = 'RouteActions';
                var msg = 'hello';
                ch.assertExchange(ex, 'direct', {
                    durable: false
                });
                ch.publish(ex, 'vm1', new Buffer(msg));
                console.log(" [x] Sent %s", msg);
                return checkCallback(null, "Connection established successfully...");
            }
        });
    });
}

//Function call
check("hello", function(err, resp) {
    if (err) {
        //Your code to handle connection failure
    } else {
        // resp gives you string "Connection established successfully...",
        //Do whatever you wanted to do after successful connection or a successful call to check method...
    }
});
```

This is not an exact code and error should be handled more gracefully, but I hope it should be enough to achieve what you want to do.

**Edit** : You could use callback APIs of this ampqlib by requiring

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

//instead of 

//var amqp = require('amqplib');

function check(msg, checkCallback) {
  amqp.connect('amqp://serv1:password1@localhost', function(err, conn) {
    conn.createChannel(function(errCreate, ch) {
      if (errCreate || err) {
        return checkCallback("Oops something went wrong while establishing connection...");
      } else {
        var ex = 'RouteActions';
        var msg = 'hello';
        ch.assertExchange(ex, 'direct', {
          durable: false
        }, function(exchangeErr, ok) {
          if (exchangeErr) {
            console.log("Error occurred while exchange..." + JSON.stringify(exchangeErr));
            return checkCallback(null, "Connection established successfully...");
          } else {
            ch.publish(ex, 'vm1', new Buffer(msg));
            console.log(" [x] Sent %s", msg);
            return checkCallback(null, "Connection established successfully...");
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

As per the docs of ampqlib they provide with promise based APIs as well as callback based so I am providing with a solution using callback, please tell me if this works also put logs in my code snippet so that if it is having some bugs you'll know.

**EDIT 2**

This is exaclty what I tried and it worked perfectly fine...

```
function check(msg, checkCallback) {
  amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
    console.log("This is err: " + JSON.stringify(err) + " conn:: ");
    conn.createChannel(function(errCreate, ch) {
      console.log("This is errCreate:: " + JSON.stringify(errCreate) + " ch:: ", ch);
      if (errCreate || err) {
        return checkCallback("Oops something went wrong while establishing connection...");
      } else {
        var ex = 'RouteActions';
        var msg = 'hello';
        ch.assertExchange(ex, 'direct', {
          durable: false
        }, function(exchangeErr, ok) {
          console.log("This is exchangeErr:: " + JSON.stringify(exchangeErr) + " ok:: ", ok);
          if (exchangeErr) {
            console.log("Error occurred while exchange..." + JSON.stringify(exchangeErr));
            return checkCallback(null, "Connection established successfully...");
          } else {
            ch.publish(ex, 'vm1', new Buffer(msg));
            console.log(" [x] Sent %s", msg);
            return checkCallback(null, "Connection established successfully...");
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
}


check('Hii', function(error, resp) {
if(error){
console.log(error);
}else{
//Rest of your code in my case...
console.log("All fine good to go...");
}
});
```

Comment: This is how i have called the function var wait = require('wait-for-stuff'); 
wait.for.function(check,'hello');

Comment: I made an edit to my answer based on what you shared as a function call could you please check it and tell me if it is a feasible solution for your requirements ?

Comment: hi this solution did not solve my problem .The problem is the whole function is not getting executed fully.it is proceeding further even before the whole function finishes.to avoid it i used wait.for.function() to force complete the function fully.but it is waiting indefenitly even after there is a return statement in the function.

Comment: If you don't use wait and simply call the function, then could you figure out exactly which steps are being skipped?

Comment: basically i have many other functions.i guess because nodejs is asynchronous and  the function it is taking time to connect it is skipping execution of the function..i have many other functions which depends on completion of this function.so i need to force execute it fully

Comment: I believe your ch.assertExchange is a type of asynchronous call, I believe it also contains a callback 
#assertExchange(exchange, type, [options, [function(err, ok) {...}]]) I found this on official docs of amoqlib, if that is the one that you are using, so I suggest you use this callback. Please check for my answer, I've added a new edit based on it and hopefully it should work. :) Btw this is the link that I referred : http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_assertExchange

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-javascript.html this is the link i have refered..But in my case the connection part code execution itself is skipping..

Comment: You mean ampqlib.connect is being skipped? Could you please log all errors of check method, the one that I provided in my latest edit, also don't forget to log err of ampqlib.connect

Comment: did not get any errors..just that the function execution gets skipped

Comment: Could you provide more code snippet in your question? As this worked just fine for me. All errors null and also returned me all logs without skipping this...

Comment: Glad it helped  :)